System.InvalidCastException from Microsoft.PowerPlatform.Dataverse.Client
We started getting the System.InvalidCastException exception intermittently in our Azure Function app 3 days ago in production and are unable to reproduce the issue in pre-production or locally.
Exception while executing function: GetQueue Error constructing handler for request of type MediatR.IRequestHandler`2[Function Name space,System.Boolean]. Register your handlers with the container. See the samples in GitHub for examples. Failed to connect to Dataverse Unable to cast object of type 'generatedProxy_2' to type 'Microsoft.PowerPlatform.Dataverse.Client.IOrganizationServiceAsync'. 

After restarting the Azure function app it starts working again.
it seams like the issue is related to the nuget package Microsoft.PowerPlatform.Dataverse.Client
Looking at the blow links its todo with scaling out.
Unable to cast object of type 'generatedProxy_2' to type 'Microsoft.PowerPlatform.Dataverse.Client.IOrganizationServiceAsync'
Unable to connect to Dataverse: Unable to cast object of type 'generatedProxy_3' to type 'Microsoft.PowerPlatform.Dataverse.Client.IOrganizationServiceAsync'
After upgrading Microsoft.PowerPlatform.Dataverse.Client from 1.0.9 to 1.1.32 the issue still persists.
Function app runtime version : ~4
.net version 6.0
Our Code on startup looks as follow
services.AddSingleton<IOrganizationServiceAsync, ServiceClient>(provider =>
{
        return GetService(d365Settings);
});

public static ServiceClient GetService(D365Settings d365Settings)
{
    var client = new ServiceClient(new Uri(d365Settings.OrganizationUri), d365Settings.ClientId, d365Settings.ClientSecret, false);

    if (client.IsReady)
        return client;

    throw new ArgumentException($"Unable to connect to CE, Error: {client.LastError}", client.LastException);
}

csproj
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions" Version="6.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions" Version="6.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions" Version="6.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.PowerPlatform.Dataverse.Client" Version="1.1.32" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\..\Core\Project1.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\..\Core\Project2.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>


Have you considered upgrading the .NET version to .NET8 as .NET6 is no longer supported?

Also, can you share your complete function code with .csproj file?

Upgrading .net version to .NET8 would be an option but don't have the time to do that now as this project is big. Would definitely consider it.

Added the csproj detail to the question.

Please share your complete function code. @Sakkie

Sorry @IkhtesamAfrin cannot do that, this project is huge and company policy wouldn't allow sharing the function code.

I believe, you might be aware that this is a known and ongoing issue. The same has been raised https://github.com/microsoft/PowerPlatform-DataverseServiceClient/issues/487 and also you have commented your issue in the same ticket.

Thanks @IkhtesamAfrin yes I also posted in that thread. I'm reaching out as much as I can for help as I have been struggling for days now.

Your exception is at MediatR.IRequestHandler. Looks like you use the MediatR  package, check the initialization code needed for MediatR to work properly.

Thanks Shinva, can you be more specific on what I need to do?

You should have MediatR bootstrap code like services.AddMediatR(cfg => cfg.RegisterServicesFromAssembly(typeof(Startup).Assembly)); The issue is most likely because of some issue with MediatR bootstrap code and where the corresponding IRequestHandler(s) are located. Please refer to https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR

You have a point. I see the developer that developed the system added MediatR using this line instead services.AddMediatR(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()); I will impement and let you know if this resolved the issue, thanks Shinva
